# RecyclerView OnClicklistener is unresponsive

Tags: android, onclick, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener

Firstly I know there are hundreds of these questions but the answers have not solved my problem. I suspect it's something small I'm missing, basically I've added a RecyclerView and need to start a new activity when a card is clicked.

I've been following this tutorial and it's been smooth sailing up until this point.
https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-the-recyclerview

This is the Recycler

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/bgImg"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/RV"
        />

</FrameLayout>
```

This is the card

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/vendor_image2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="240dp"
        android:padding="5dp" />

    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/vendor_image2"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/vendor_name2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/vendor_content2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/vendor_name2"
            android:textColor="@color/text_col"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/vendor_suburb2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            android:textColor="@color/text_col"
            android:layout_below="@+id/vendor_name2"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />
        <RatingBar
            android:id="@+id/MyRating2"
            style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/vendor_suburb2"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:isIndicator="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:numStars="5"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:rating="3.5"
            android:stepSize="0.1" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

And finally the Adapter and Handler

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RatingBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.iconiccode.android.guestloc8tor.SQL.DatabaseHandler;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.DisplayImageOptions;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoaderConfiguration;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.assist.ImageScaleType;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.display.FadeInBitmapDisplayer;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.List;

public class VendorRecycleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VendorRecycleAdapter.VendorHolder>
{
    public List<Vendor> vendorList;
    private DatabaseHandler dbHandler = new DatabaseHandler(MyApp.getContext());
    private Vendor currentVendor;
    int cate;
    Activity thiscontext;
    public VendorRecycleAdapter(Activity context, int Cate)
    {
        this.cate=Cate;
        this.thiscontext=context;
    }

    @Override
    public VendorHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(thiscontext);

        //View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, parent, false);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.vendor_list_cards,parent,false);
        return new VendorHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(VendorHolder holder, int position)
    {
        vendorList = dbHandler.getVendorData(cate);
        currentVendor = vendorList.get(position);

        // Get the image string from the Vendor object
        String vendorImage = currentVendor.getImage();

        Log.e("Vendor Adapter Image", vendorImage);

        // Get the name string from the Vendor object
        String vendorName = currentVendor.getCompanyName();

        Log.e("Vendor Adapter Name", vendorName);

        // Get the content string from the Vendor object
        String vendorContent = currentVendor.getContent();

        // Get the location string from the Vendor object
        String vendorSuburb = currentVendor.getSuburb();

        Log.e("Vendor Adapter Suburb", vendorSuburb);

        // Find the TextView with view ID vendor_name

        // Display the name of the current vendor in that TextView
        holder.Vvendor_name.setText(vendorName);

        holder.Vvendor_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.loading);

        ImageLoader imageLoader;
        DisplayImageOptions options;
        imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();

        String url = vendorImage;
        imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(MyApp.getContext()));
        options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.loading)
                .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.b4f29385)
                .resetViewBeforeLoading(true).cacheOnDisk(true)
                .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)
                .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565).considerExifParams(true)
                .displayer(new FadeInBitmapDisplayer(300)).build();

        imageLoader.displayImage(url, holder.Vvendor_image);

        // Find the TextView with view ID vendor_content
        holder.Vvendor_content.setText(vendorContent);

        holder.Vvendor_suburb.setText(vendorSuburb);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount()
    {
        vendorList = dbHandler.getVendorData(cate);
        return vendorList.size();
    }


    public class VendorHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener
    {
        public ImageView Vvendor_image;
        public TextView Vvendor_name,Vvendor_content,Vvendor_suburb;
        public  RatingBar Vrating;
        public VendorHolder(View itemView)
        {
            //These pull as null
            super(itemView);
            Vvendor_image = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.vendor_image2);
            Vvendor_name = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.vendor_name2);
            Vvendor_content =(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.vendor_content2);
            Vvendor_suburb = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.vendor_suburb2);
            Vrating = (RatingBar) itemView.findViewById(R.id.MyRating2);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
//            int position = getAdapterPosition();
//            currentVendor = vendorList.get(position);
            Intent intent = new Intent(thiscontext,VendorDetailsActivity.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
            String Category = Integer.toString(cate);
            JSONObject message = currentVendor.getAllData();
            try {
                intent.putExtra("IMAGE", message.getString("IMAGE"));
                intent.putExtra("URL", message.getString("URL"));
                intent.putExtra("CONTENT", message.getString("CONTENT"));
                intent.putExtra("COMPANY_NAME", message.getString("COMPANY_NAME"));
                intent.putExtra("TEL", message.getString("TEL"));
                intent.putExtra("BOOKING_URL", message.getString("BOOKING_URL"));
                intent.putExtra("LAT", message.getString("LAT"));
                intent.putExtra("LON", message.getString("LON"));
                intent.putExtra("STREET", message.getString("STREET"));
                intent.putExtra("SUBURB", message.getString("SUBURB"));
                intent.putExtra("PROVINCE", message.getString("PROVINCE"));
                intent.putExtra("CITY", message.getString("CITY"));
                intent.putExtra("CAT",Category);
            } catch (JSONException json)
            {
                Log.e("ERROR", json.getMessage());
            }
            thiscontext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just forgot to set the onClickListener in your ViewHolder constructor:

```
    public VendorHolder(View itemView)
    {
        //These pull as null
        super(itemView);
        Vvendor_image = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.vendor_image2);
        Vvendor_name = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.vendor_name2);
        Vvendor_content =(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.vendor_content2);
        Vvendor_suburb = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.vendor_suburb2);
        Vrating = (RatingBar) itemView.findViewById(R.id.MyRating2);

        // If it should be triggered only when clicking on a specific view, replace itemView with the view you want.
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
```

Comment: I knew it was something Silly, would you mind showing me where exactly to place it ?